# How to add color inside a formula in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to add a random color to this formula =word.ο.α.ας.v2&"άς" by which I get this output αγαπ**άς**. This is part of my conugation table in which I want to add colors to the last letters, so I can see what the endig of the word is.

Is that possible? Thank you kindly!

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  The "formula" you entered is not a valid Excel function, for one thing.  See [this section](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on writing a good question.  To answer your final question, no, it is not possible to format text using a formula in Excel.  But there is a possible [workaround](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/75061-formatting-text-bold-within-formula.html) using textboxes that may help you.

Comment: To whomever voted this question down:  It would be helpful (and courteous)  for you to at least give the guy some brief feedback on how to improve his question.

Comment: I see. I do need that for my dictionary, which I am creating now. Maybe I will write a code for the whole conjugation table inside javascript or php, so I don't need to make use of Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done with formulas. You would need  VBA for that, and even then it's not exactly trivial to achieve.